# How to create dynamic datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to create a list of datatable dynamically, something like :

```
 DataTable[] Mydt = new DataTable();
```

and fill it like :

```
Mydt[i] = .....
```

Do you know if such a syntax exist in c# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use following code sample,

```
    private static DataSet SampleData()
    {
        DataSet sampleDataSet = new DataSet();
        sampleDataSet.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DataTable sampleDataTable = sampleDataSet.Tables.Add("SampleData");

        sampleDataTable.Columns.Add("FirstColumn", typeof(string));
        sampleDataTable.Columns.Add("SecondColumn", typeof(string));
        DataRow sampleDataRow;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 49; i++)
        {
            sampleDataRow = sampleDataTable.NewRow();
            sampleDataRow["FirstColumn"] = "Cell1: " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            sampleDataRow["SecondColumn"] = "Cell2: " + i.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            sampleDataTable.Rows.Add(sampleDataRow);
        }

        return sampleDataSet;
    }
```

Comment: you should add a call to sampleDataTable.AcceptChanges() before you return the table in order to mark all rows as unchanged.